# Install Shortcut from VS2010 setup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, shortcut-file

VS2010 contains a ‘setup’ project that creates an installation package.
I need a short cut to the app that will be installed on the user’s desktop. The shortcut I know how to create with the setup/Install is a ‘special’ shortcut and I can’t use it to drop files onto it (and launch the app from it).
Anyone knows how to create a full-features-shortcut that will follow the user’s specified installation path (if he changes it)?

Comment: off topic: setup projects are no longer supported in VS2011. Use Wix or some other program to create setup projects in vs2011

Comment: @Martin The OP specified "VS2010", and things aren't off topic just because they are no longer supported. (If the post has been edited, it is not reflected here.)

Comment: @Okuma It wrote "off topic" because the OP asked about "VS2010", not because it was no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

To create a shortcut in a Visual Studio setup project, you can try this:

- go to the File System Editor
- select "User's Desktop" folder
- right-click in the right pane (the files list)
- select "Create New Shortcut" context menu item
- select the target file when prompted

I'm not sure what you mean by "special shortcut", but this is the only type of shortcut you can create with Visual Studio.

Comment: This shortcut doen't allow you to use drag & drop onto it. So after installing the app the user can't use all of the app's features. Moreover if you look at its properties it looks different than the one you create manually

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to disable advertised shortcuts with a tool like Orca. More info here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/d87e8737-dc71-4a5d-a3e7-6653888dd129/?prof=required